# How to set a value of input field as a parameter of function?

Tags: javascript, function, random

I tried to use input as a parameter of a function. The problem is that when I use numbers as parameters (for example: getRandomNumber(1,20)) all works right. But when I'm using the approach represented below and type min = 2 and max = 5 I'm getting numbers 0,1,2,3. How to force it works like getRandomNumber(1,20)?

I guess mistake in the `Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)`

```html
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type = "button" value = "Get random number" onclick = "getRandomNumber(document.getElementById('min').value,document.getElementById('max').value)">
      <input type = "input" id = "min" placeholder = "min">
      <input type = "input" id = "max" placeholder = "max">
      <script>
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    
        function getRandomNumber(min,max) {
          p.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below:

`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min`

and also convert the inputs to number for example use 
`document.getElementById('min').valueAsNumber`